# trigger function not valid

Tags: postgresql, triggers, timestamp

Im new to triggers and banging my head through different documentation that I all find slightly different which make it hard to find a common pattern of the different part of the trigger. 
Anyway..

I am trying to build a very simple query. I want to update the column `endredato` when an update is done for each row with a timestamp `NOW()`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_endredato()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
NEW.endredato = NOW()
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I try to create this function of the trigger do I get an error "Syntax error at or near "NEW". Could someone please point out why this is not valid?

Best regards

Comment: You are missing a `;` after the `now()`

Comment: Because you are missing an `;` after `now()`